# Convert php 2D array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Firstly what I am trying is creating a pie chart using google chart api. There I have to feed an javascript array of array. Now what I have in server side is an php array of following structure:

```
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "price": 25200
  },
  {
    "name": "b",
    "price": 13500
  }
]
```

What I need is:

```
[
  [
    "a": 25200
  ],
  [
    "b": 13500
  ]
]
```

What I have so far - used the following php function to convert.

```
public function convert($packages){
    $packageShare = array(array());
    $count = count($packages);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){    
        $pack = array();

        $pack[$packages[$i]['name']] = $packages[$i]['price'];

        $packageShare[$i] = $pack;
   }
   return $packageShare;
}
```

But the output was not what I want. Here is what the above function returns:

```
[
  {
    "a": 25200
  },
  {
    "b": 13500
  }
]
```

N.B. I need to feed this array in `google chart api` which takes something like this in javascript.

[ [0, 0],   [1, 10],  [2, 12] ]

What can be the standard way to feed?

Comment: The json array which your php is generating should work. Have a look at [this link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example). And what's the error that you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for [ [0, 0], [1, 10], [2, 12] ] format, it's an array of array. You can get this with

```
$output = array_map(function($v){return [$v['name'], $v['price']];}, $array);
print_r(json_encode($output));
```

output:

```
[["a",25200],["b",13500]]
```

Here is also other format,

```
<?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!
$array = array(array('name'=>'a', 'price'=>25200),array('name'=>'b', 'price'=>13500));
print_r(json_encode($array));
echo "\n";
$output = array_map(function($v){return [$v['name'], $v['price']];}, $array);
print_r(json_encode($output));
echo "\n";
$output1 = array_map(function($v){return array($v['name'] => $v['price']);}, $array);
print_r(json_encode($output1));
echo "\n";
```

output:

```
[{"name":"a","price":25200},{"name":"b","price":13500}]
[["a",25200],["b",13500]]
[{"a":25200},{"b":13500}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function convert($packages){
    $a = json_decode($packages,true);
    $count = sizeof($a);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){    
        $b[][$a[$i]['name']]=$a[$i]['price'];
   }
   return $b;
}
```

Output of `print_r($b)` will be

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [a] => 25200 ) [1] => Array ( [b] => 13500 ) )
```